# How to write the onclick listener for a view after animation?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have animating the view from one place to another, after animation done I have written the code like this,

```
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            imageView.setOnClickListener(this); 
        }
```

But I cant able to click that view. No response from that view.

Comment: Does it work if you click on the place where the view was originally, before the animation executed?

Comment: do you have onClick method on your class?

Comment: Yes its working before the animation starts.

Comment: @evilone yes I have included onclick listener

Answer (score 0):

You should move the view after the animation to the new position. You can use LayoutParams.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the view after the animation to the new position. You can use LayoutParams. use the code like this..

```
      transAnimation= new TranslateAnimation(0, 
 sourceX-destinationX,0,sourceY-destinationY); // right to left

             transAnimation.setDuration(1000);
             //transAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
             transAnimation.setFillAfter(false);
             view.startAnimation(transAnimation);

transAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                    @Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    }

                    @Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

Log.v("hari", "--------onAnimationEnd--------");

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeNew 
  = new    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
          relativeNew.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
         relativeNew.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT);
     relativeNew.setMargins(125, 10, 10, 10);
    view.setLayoutParams(relativeNew);

 }
```